# (C) Pointer not properly evaluation dereference operator

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic

I am working on a project for school and I have managed to figure out a work around by doing something really clunky with my code. I have a structure that holds multiple fields, and I am trying to access the following field (as it is declared in the struct named current_event).

```
int *number_of_couples;
```

and later down into the program I call this value so I can dynamically allocate an array based on this *number_of_couples field. Essentially I am trying to use this as a "length" operator as C does not have (good) solution.

Before I was trying to implement the following code:

```
int *permutable_array;
permutable_array = malloc((current_event->number_of_couples) * sizeof(int)); //Line 91
if(permutable_array == NULL){
    panic("permutable_array"); //Ensures that Malloc was successful. 
}
```

which would in turn throw the following error:
Line 91: error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'int *' and 'unsigned int')

I have made a very sloppy work around because at this point I just want to get the program working (hour three of pure programming! rock on!). So I implemented:

```
int *permutable_array;
int avoid_my_bug = (int) current_event->number_of_couples;
permutable_array = malloc(avoid_my_bug * sizeof(int));
if(permutable_array == NULL){
    panic("permutable_array");
}
```

Which works. Now I somewhat understand the error that it is telling me. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I stored the value of number_of_couples as a pointer within current_event, which is also a pointer. So really if the value of number_of_couples is 4, the path the program makes to get to that value is:

```
ptr_to_current_event -> ptr_to_number_of_couples -> 4
```

I can use my sloppy work-around, but it is obvious that I am doing it to avoid a bug. I would rather learn why the code will not compile. I also tried doing:

```
permutable_array = malloc((*current_event->number_of_couples) * sizeof(int)); //Line 91
```

which should have dereferenced the pointer returned by current_event->number_of_couples, however it crashes. Any solutions?

****EDIT****
It is initialized by the following line of code:

```
fscanf(input_file, "%i", &current_event->number_of_couples);
```

and is referenced at least three times (there is a valid int value stored in it) by the program before reaching my code. Remember, the second bit works, therefore it is definitely initialized.

Comment: So you're saying `number_of_couples` is a pointer type?

Comment: Yes, I would rather allocate it on the stack than the heap, so I am dynamically creating a spot for it in memory. It was essential to my program and losing it would cause serious problems.

Comment: I suggest you remove all the casts from your program and fix all the errors and warnings. This may include changing your definitions, too.

Comment: there is only one warning in my code currently and that is I have a swap function and it claims that a variable is initialized but never used. Other than that before posting this is when I fixed all of my casts to conform to the compilers wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing integer values inside pointers. Pointers are made to point at things, you should rarely need to convert a pointer to an integer type. If you do you should use either the `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` types.

You should either dereference the pointer (assuming it is pointing at a valid `int`) or change the type of `number_of_couples` so that it is not a pointer. If you leave it as a pointer, you must ensure it is pointing to a valid `int` object before trying to dereference it, but based on your usage and context above, it doesn't need to be a pointer.

Comment: I thought I would take the path of "rather safe than sorry" by declaring the value as a pointer to an int rather than an int itself. I guess that was not the case. I am always worried that when I go to call it later and I statically called it I will have lost it on the heap rather than declaring it from the stack, do you get what I mean?

Comment: When you assign an `int` to another `int` it doesn't matter what happens to the original, the value was *copied* to the new `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You must *dereference* the pointer to int

```
*(current_event->number_of_couples) * sizeof(int)
```

Casting the pointer to an int, will give you the *address* of number_of_couples as an integer. This might be some arbitrary large number like 0xf97e1892, for example.

The crash could be a result of `number_of_couples` not being initialized. You must allocate memory for this pointer. If it is not initialized, it will point to an arbitrary location.

If you initialize it with an integer `number_of_couples = 5`, it will point to invalid memory. The pointer is only valid, if you allocate memory from the heap or point to another integer variable.

All in all, it seems in your case it is best to define `number_of_couples` as an int and avoid all the potential pitfalls.

```
int number_of_couples;
```

Then, you can just allocate the memory as in your first example.

Comment: please read the last line of the question, I was editing it while you were responding.

Comment: The value is initialized, by the time the code reaches this line of code it has called this value (and successfully converted it to it's int value) at least four times.

Comment: @dsiebert424 Initializing with `fscanf` is like assigning an integer. As I already suggested in my answer, declare `number_of_couples` as an int.

Answer (score 0):

You should use *(current_event->number_of_couples), that way you will get the value to which pointer is pointing. If you do not use * you will get an address of pointer which you can cast to int but that is not what you want.
Try putting parentheses in your code around current_event->number_of_couples and then use *. If it doesnt help then something else is causing crashing.

Comment: please read the last line of the question, I was editing it while you were responding.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is crashing when you dereference this pointer, the chances are that it is pointing to invalid or uninitialised memory. You don't indicate in your question where this gets initialised, but dereferencing an uninitialised pointer is asking for trouble - look into where it gets initialised and if it is pointing to dynamic memory or not.